# Getting the contents of a file in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, io

In my project I have a plain text file called GAME.js, and I'm trying to get the contents of the file.

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"GAME.js" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

sounds like it should work, but it's just returning an empty string.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 8):

Put `GAME.js` into the `Resources` folder in your Xcode project and use the following code to get the contents of the file.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GAME" ofType:@"js"];
NSString* gameFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass in a [`NSError`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it will tell you exactly what the problem is:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"GAME.js" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
}
```

[`NSError` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

Also, check to see if it is in your documents directory which can be accessed with `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *fullPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GAME.js"];

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
}
```

Comment: o_O Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 260.) - (null)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterperted that comment to be an error in the code I gave you, not your actual error...  I would have to google that error code (260), but look at @ChrisLedet answer, that will probably work.  If his answer doesnt work, try what I added in my last answer edit.

Comment: Note that in Cocoa (Touch) one should [check the method return value before inspecting the error output parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html).

Comment: @Bavarious is correct, the code above is just an example and would need to be modified to fit your project and follow proper guidelines before being used in a production environment.